# Which command for cut off string data in T-SQL at specific symbol?

Tags: string, t-sql

Here is the data I have :

- BS120-S12-H01
- b120-rjos-H03
- BS12-J02-H03

and here is what i want to get from the sql :

1. H01
2. H03
3. H03

Comment: If it's always 3 chars you can simply use `right`: `select right(data, 3) from table`.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to reverse the string, then use `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT` to find the substring up and excluding the first hyphen.  Then, reverse that substring to get the final output.

```
SELECT
    data,
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(data), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(data)) - 1)) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use bellow function for return certain string.

-- User-defined function to implement Oracle INSTR in SQL Server
  CREATE FUNCTION INSTR (@str VARCHAR(8000), @substr VARCHAR(255), @start INT, @occurrence INT)
  RETURNS INT
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @found INT = @occurrence,
            @pos INT = @start;

```
WHILE 1=1 
BEGIN
    -- Find the next occurrence
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@substr, @str, @pos);

    -- Nothing found
    IF @pos IS NULL OR @pos = 0
        RETURN @pos;

    -- The required occurrence found
    IF @found = 1
        BREAK;

    -- Prepare to find another one occurrence
    SET @found = @found - 1;
    SET @pos = @pos + 1;
END

RETURN @pos;
```

END
  GO

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share us your logic to deal with your data? So that we can have a good direction and make some test.

I guess your logic and I will provide you three ways. Hope it can help you.

```
---drop table test 

create table test 
(string varchar(20))

insert into test values 
('BS120-S12-H01'),
('b120-rjos-H03'),
('BS12-J02-H03')
```

------1-------

```
select right(string,3) as result from test
```

------2-------

```
SELECT
    right(string,CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(string))-1) AS result
FROM test;
```

------3-------

```
SELECT
    substring(string,len(string)-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(string))+2,3) AS result
FROM test;
```

Best Regards, 
Rachel